# Casting a swift type to the same type, why does this work?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, casting

Why does the following line compile and work in swift?

```
employeeListing.text = (jumperCablesRoles[row] as! [String] as [String]).joinWithSeparator("...")
```

It appears I'm casting an array of strings to an array of strings which I would think is the exact same thing.  It works but I don't know why, can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok a few points with your code:

First, `jumperCablesRoles[row] as! [String]` is a potentially dangerous action in Swift as you are force unwrapping (casting) `jumperCablesRoles[row]` as an array of Strings. Read more about saving ponies [here](http://alisoftware.github.io/swift/2015/09/06/thinking-in-swift-1/).

A better solution would be to something like:

```
if let role = jumperCablesRoles[row] as? [String] {
     employeeListing.text = role.joinWithSeparator("...") // role is guaranteed to be an Array of Strings. Safe to operate on it. 
} else {
     // jumperCablesRoles[row] is not an array of strings, handle so here.
}
```

This checks that `jumperCablesRoles[row]` is an actual array of strings without blowing up, if not you can handle it.

To stop you casting you can also specify the type of `jumperCablesRoles` like so:

```
jumperCablesRoles: [[String]] = []
```

This would allow you to use `jumperCablesRoles` directly as:

```
employeeListing.text = jumperCablesRoles.joinWithSeparator("...")
```

Second, to answer your question about casting an array of strings to an array of strings (`... as! [String] as [String]`). What you are essentially saying with this line of code is:

```
let role = jumperCableRoles[row] as! [String] // role is an Array of Strings
let role2 = role as [String] // Specifying an object as an Array of Strings when it already is an Array of Strings. Which is trivial.
```

Comment: `!` is potentially dangerous depending on context. If you are sure about your data types, then using `!` is good style.

Comment: Then why not specify the type before hand, as mentioned above and negate the danger in the first place?